# Django template 'url' tag not rendering as form field attribute value

Tags: django, django-templates

In my Django app, I'm trying to implement an ajax request, for that, I would need a specific field in the form and setting the ajax request URL as an attribute value to the field. But the URL template tag is not rendering on the HTML.

```
#urls.py
...
path('checkdata', check_data, name='ajaxcheck')

#forms.py
fld_name = forms.CharField(label='Name', max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'ajax-data-url': "{% 'ajaxcheck' %}"}))

Output HTML:
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" ajax-data-url="{% 'ajaxcheck' %}" maxlength="100" class="textinput textInput form-control" required="" id="id_name">
```

Comment: You can't put template tags like this in a form field attribute, as you can see they aren't executed (note it should have been `{% url 'ajaxcheck' %}` anyway). Since **forms.py** is just python, just use `reverse('ajaxcheck')`.

Comment: Thanks @dirkgroten. I tried the ‘reverse’ but it didn’t work , ended up in circular import. Found online a solution to use reverse_lazy and it worked. Thanks again for pointing the right direction.